# Why does JaCoCo see my JUnit but ignore my Spock tests?

Tags: java, gradle, junit, spock, jacoco

I have a [project](https://github.com/rossdrew/emuRox/blob/master/build.gradle) that uses JUnit to form simple unit tests (`test/java`) and Spock to perform more complex, data-driven unit tests (`test/groovy`).  I build all this with Gradle.

My problem is that generating a JaCoCo report, results in very low code coverage because it only seems to take the JUnit tests into account.  I can run these tests all together just fine in IntelliJ, Pitest and via Gradle also finds all tests and reports the correct line coverage.

(I need JaCoCo to set up my GitHub shield)

How do I get JaCoCo to report line coverage using both testing frameworks?

**build.gradle**

```
group 'com.rox'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'
apply plugin: 'info.solidsoft.pitest'
apply plugin: 'application'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.codehaus.groovy', name: 'groovy-all', version: '2.3.11'
    compile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    compile group: 'org.hamcrest', name: 'hamcrest-all', version: '1.3'
    compile group: 'org.spockframework', name: 'spock-core', version: '1.1-groovy-2.4-rc-1'
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "info.solidsoft.gradle.pitest:gradle-pitest-plugin:1.1.4"
    }
}

task runDebugUI(type: JavaExec, group: 'run') {
    classpath sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    main = mainClassName = 'com.rox.emu.P6502.dbg.UI'
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I remove `src/test/java` from your project and generate JaCoCo report using `./gradlew clean build jacocoTestReport`, then report in `build/reports/jacoco/test/html/index.html` shows some coverage. Since only `src/test/groovy` was left - I conclude that Spock tests are actually taken into account. The only package that is not covered - is `com.rox.emu.P6502.dbg.ui`, but seems that you don't have any tests for it.

Since generated report contains coverage, I'm guessing that you have problem with some other tool that supposed to import coverage data. And since you mentioned "GitHub shield", I'm guessing that problem might be with https://codecov.io - your [build in Travis states](https://s3.amazonaws.com/archive.travis-ci.org/jobs/191958516/log.txt):

> No coverage report found.
>
> Please visit http://docs.codecov.io/docs/supported-languages

According to https://github.com/codecov/example-gradle/blob/master/README.md#add-jacoco-plugin : integration of JaCoCo into Codecov requires generation of JaCoCo XML report. So add

```
jacocoTestReport {
    reports {
        xml.enabled true
    }
}
```

into `build.gradle` and don't forget to execute `gradlew jacocoTestReport`.

As a note: JaCoCo itself is independent from testing framework. To get coverage your tests should just execute classes that were instrumented by JaCoCo, what is  achieved by using [JaCoCo Java agent](http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/agent.html):

> This mechanism allows in-memory pre-processing of all class files during class loading **independent of the application framework**.

And JaCoCo Gradle plugin simply enhances Gradle tasks, so that they will use this agent.

Comment: Wow, you really looked into that.  Thanks.  Seems it was doing a weird thing where it was using an old test compile for me, the clean, build tests and re-run report fixed it.
Thanks

Comment: p.s. my code coverage on GitHub was disabled till I fixed this :)

Comment: @RossDrew you've just met one of JaCoCo developers ;) and we're glad to help, especially when easy-to-use reproducer is provided ;) cool that your issue resolved!